# Как сделать кнопку назад в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, input, button

Как сделать кнопку назад на Cancel, так, чтобы при возврате происходило автосохранение изменений в сцене из которой хотят выйти.

Comment: C Unity я знаком очень отдаленно, но подозреваю что ты сам ответил на свой вопрос: Сохранить контейнер с классами в фал и потом его восстанавливать

Comment: Я не знаю каким скриптом нужно для этого воспользоваться.

Comment: Конкретизируйте ваш, вопрос. В данном описании непонятно, какие измения, в каких объектах вы хотите сохранить: это изменения состояния ваших кастомных классов, положение объектов на сцене или еще что-то другое?

Answer (score 1):

Если нужна кнопка `Cancel`, по нажатию на которую все происходит:

1) Создаете кнопку

2) вешаете на нее скрипт с функцией (добавьте в скрипт `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;`)

```
 public void CancelMyScene()
    {
        // аналогично для float или string, но пишите SetFloat или SetString
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Тут ключ, на который сохраняются значения", 42); // 42 - тут любое int, какое хотите сохранить
        // все, что нужно сохранить
        SceneManager.LoadScene (0); // загружаете нужную сцену
    }
```

3) выбираете кнопку, и в `On Click()` жмете `+`

4) переносите скрипт на кнопке в `None`, который появился в `On Click()`

5) в `On Click()` жмете по `No Function`, там ищите вашу функцию и выбираете ее.

Все это можно делать не вручную, а в коде.

---

Вариант 2. Если нужно сделать так, чтобы все это делалось при нажатии кнопки "назад" на телефоне/планшете:

1) Создаете скрипт на любом объекте на сцене

2)

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement; // обязательно

public class BUTEST : MonoBehaviour {

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android ||
            Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsEditor)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape))
            {
                // аналогично для float или string, но пишите SetFloat или SetString
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Тут ключ, на который сохраняются значения", 42); // 42 - тут любое int, какое хотите сохранить
                // все, что нужно сохранить
                SceneManager.LoadScene (0); // загружаете нужную сцену
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Наверно, можно лучше, но и так работает

Comment: Окей, я частично понял. Но а если мне нужно сделать кнопку выход из настроек допустим, и чтобы при выходе из настроек они сохранились? Просто не хочу делать отдельно кнопку сохранения настроек

Comment: И ещё хочу спросить, как сделать кнопку назад, допустим чтобы закрыть меню паузы, или перейти из одного пункта главного меню назад в само главное меню?

Comment: " Просто не хочу делать отдельно кнопку сохранения настроек" - ну так сделайте на ту же. " закрыть меню паузы, или перейти из одного пункта главного меню назад в само главное меню" - либо делать "настройки" и "меню" разными сценами и использовать этот способ, либо поискать на официальном сайте юнити "как сделать главное меню". Там в видеоуроке способ без изменения сцены